# AWS EC2 Elastic Beanstalk issue

Tags: python, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I wrote a Python-based RESTful API that connect to my company's service. It  runs on our EC2 instance.

For some odd reason, `GET` requests work fine, but when a `POST` request is invoked it doesn't show up.

We tried to double, triple checked the links and still the error persist. It is almost like if the EC2 is blocking the request from going through.

I was just wondering if anyone has ran into this problem and found a valid solution to it.

For future reference, this all works on the local machine on which it was developed on. But, I can't show my code since it would leak thousands of user metadata which is against our privacy policy.

Edit: If this is to any help, the framework "FLASK" was used to create the Restful API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For tips on asking a question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide a minimal example of code that can reproduce the problem (obviously without showing private information). Try and reproduce the problem with a minimal code example, then Edit your question to show the code and the error.

Comment: Until and unless you are using CloudFront in front of Beanstalk; all get and post requests are handled similarly by Beanstalk.. If GET is working fine that means it is not an issue with SecurityGroups. Either it is CloudFront or your application issue where u are doing something wrong in post request

Comment: Cloudfront? It's just a normal AWS EC2 Amazon's Ubuntu Instance.